# Cassandra Table Count Timeout

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I try to get number of rows in a table. But cassandra turns timeout for this query select count(*) from events ;

I think that my tables is too big so if ı give a timeout value for my query, it turns always timeout cqlsh --request-timeout=200000

Table size 1.3TB. Is there any way to learn How many rows in this table ?

Comment: Do you need the exact count or estimated  count is enough?

Comment: Actually, I need exact count

Answer (score 1):

Do not use count(*) to get no of rows.You can use the following link and download the jar file to get the count.
https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-count

Answer (score 0):

One solution that can help you find the total rows in Pagination of result.

Please refer to the below doc :

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/paging/

Note : You can also try ALLOW FILTERING for development! But the use of it should avoided as it is very expensive query, might impact the performance of the cassandra.

Comment: I'm intrigued by your solution, but it eludes me how can Pagination help in determining a count on the query. I tried that in`C#` using Datastax C# Cassandra Driver, and unfortunately did not come to any helpful things. If only I had the information how many pages there are I could determine the count, +/- pageSize... Could you elaborate a little more on that?